# Security of a password container in the cloud

Tags: password-management, cloud-storage

I currently use [Keypass](http://keepass.info) to manage my passwords and I sync the container between my desktop and my smartphone via USB.

My wife has an older tablet that I cannot sync via USB because I cannot mount it as an external disk, but I know that Keypass can sync a container on Dropbox. The problem is that IMHO a master password is not secure enough for a file in the cloud.

Am I truely paranoiac and should I use a Dropbox container with no further precaution, or are there other options to make the operation reasonably secure?

Comment: you could sync a password protected archive and unpack it on the tablet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really think that you are *that* much at risk? That's what it comes down to.

As long as you have a good passcode, it is going to be more than enough unless you are expecting ongoing, long-term, government-level aggression.

Make the passcode long and as random as you can while still remembering it.

You could also try to hide the TC file with an innocuous sounding name.

You could go further and require a secondary key using a file such as a particular mp3 but honestly, the more complex you make things, the more likely you are to end up locked out of your own password database which is an even worse (and ultimately more likely) scenario.

Comment: The problem is in fact the passcode that I must share with my wife and is much weaker than all the random ones from the Keypass container. But the additional keyfile looks like what I need. Thank you for that answer

Answer (score 0):

Find a service that offers file level encryption and is cross platform. I would list a few here, but not very familiar with the rules for recommendations. Then encrypt your DB and sync it with dropbox to your phone and decrypt it locally there. Finally, point Keypass mobile at the decrypted file.

IMHO, I trust Keepass's encryption implementation enough to not bother with the extra effort of encrypting the DB a second time.

Comment: I agree with you and think that keypass encryption is strong enough. The problem with a password container is that it can contain sensitive informations (bank account password for example). So if somebody can guess the master password he can decode everything. The problem seems to be more with the key than with the encryption algo...

Comment: @Sergei Ballesta Makes sense. However, do consider something like viivo for encrypting individual files and syncing them.